# How to change the directory where cx_Freeze creates the "build" and "dist" folders?

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

python setup.py bdist_msi

How can change the directory where cx_Freeze creates the "build" and "dist" folders?
When I run this command it creates them inside the python directory where I put the setup.py and myapp.py files, but I want to create them somewhere else.

Answer (score 6):

There's an option for that; when you execute your distutils setup script, e.g. `python setup.py build`, you can specify the directory as `python setup.py build -b ..\somewhere\else\`.

Alternatively, you can set it in the code in the option dict. e.g. change

```
options = {
    'includes': ['numpy.core._methods'],
    'excludes': ['tkinter']
}
setup(name="Application", options=options, executables=[Executable("run.py", base=None)]
```

in your setup script to

```
options = {
    'includes': ['numpy.core._methods'],
    'excludes': ['tkinter'],
    'build_exe': '..\\somewhere\\else\\'
}
setup(name="Application", options=options, executables=[Executable("run.py", base=None)]
```

Note that I've had some slightly different behavior with the two solutions; the first will put all of the files into a folder *inside* `somewhere\else`, whereas the second will simply put all of the files into `somewhere\else`.

Comment: If you're specifying more options in `build_exe`, such as `packages`, you can do: `'build_exe': {'build_exe': '..\\somewhere\\else\\', 'packages': packages}`